# Reading Excel Spreadsheet with C#, unequal Column/Values

Tags: c#, xml, excel, xml-parsing

I have an excel spreadsheet output as XML with the columns defined as this:

```
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell ss:StyleID="ColumnHead">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">#</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="ColumnHead">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">prefix</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="ColumnHead">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">name</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="ColumnHead">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">label</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="ColumnHead">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">totalLabel</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="ColumnHead">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">base schema</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="ColumnHead">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">systemid</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="ColumnHead">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">prohibit</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
```

And here is one example row:

```
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderNumberCell">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="Number">1</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderCell">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">ifrs</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderCell">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">AccountingProfit</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderCell">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Accounting profit</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderCell"/>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderCell">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">full_entry_point</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
```

The problem is, how do I detect which cells are missing which columns?  Is it required that the source have a blank self closing tag for all empty cells in order for me to be able to pair up each column to each value every time?

How would I manage this situation in C#?  I have the bare minimum right, not sure how to separate it to account for missing columns.

```
 if (reader.Name == "ss:Data")
      {                                       

          while (reader.Read())
               Response.Write(reader.Value);
      }
```

Comment: The fifth cell in the row is blank and you can tell because it does have a closing Tag `/>`

Comment: But the last two columns are also missing, systemid and prohibit.  Does it only blank out tags that show in the middle?  I have other worksheets with closing tags that show up in the end.

Comment: Its been while (approx 2yrs ago I worked with Excel as XML). I'm thinking the XML wouldn't include the last two columns if they are blank in order to minimise the size of the XML file. However we can see it does include blank cells in the middle.

Comment: That would make sense but every other worksheet in the same excel book has blank tags for the ending elements if they are empty.  They all have matching cols/rows.  In either case, would you know how to take the code above and handle that empty middle tag?

Answer (score 1):

You could use LinqToExcel to read the data, and it should be faster because it doesn't have to load the whole file. However, LinqToExcel uses OLEDB to read the file instead of the Open XML SDK.

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
var firstRow = (from c in excel.Worksheet()
                select c).First();
```

Please see the rest of the [documentation for LinqToExcel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel#welcome-to-the-linqtoexcel-project).

Otherwise you can do it with LINQ:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace UnitTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestCode
    {
        [Test]
        public void ReadExcelCellTest()
        {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\TheFile.xml");
            XNamespace workbookNameSpace = @"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";

            // Get worksheet
            var query = from w in document.Elements(workbookNameSpace + "Workbook").Elements(workbookNameSpace + "Worksheet")
                        where w.Attribute(workbookNameSpace + "Name").Value.Equals("Settings")
                        select w;
            List<XElement> foundWoksheets = query.ToList<XElement>();
            if (foundWoksheets.Count() <= 0) { throw new ApplicationException("Worksheet Settings could not be found"); }
            XElement worksheet = query.ToList<XElement>()[0];

            // Get the row for "Seat"
            query = from d in worksheet.Elements(workbookNameSpace + "Table").Elements(workbookNameSpace + "Row").Elements(workbookNameSpace + "Cell").Elements(workbookNameSpace + "Data")
                    where d.Value.Equals("Seat")
                    select d;
            List<XElement> foundData = query.ToList<XElement>();
            if (foundData.Count() <= 0) { throw new ApplicationException("Row 'Seat' could not be found"); }
            XElement row = query.ToList<XElement>()[0].Parent.Parent;

            // Get value cell of Etl_SPIImportLocation_ImportPath setting
            XElement cell = row.Elements().ToList<XElement>()[1];

            // Get the value "Leon"
            string cellValue = cell.Elements(workbookNameSpace + "Data").ToList<XElement>()[0].Value;

            Console.WriteLine(cellValue);
        }
    }
}
```